Borsh rustEnum Definition in typescript
Im trying to create this enum from idl into a borsh schema to be able to deserialize the data from the program
{
      "name": "GameState",
      "type": {
        "kind": "enum",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "STARTED"
          },
          {
            "name": "RoundEnded",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "winner",
                "type": "pubkey"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "PrizeWithdrew"
          }
        ]
      }
    }

I've tried this
import * as borsh from '@coral-xyz/borsh';

const Started = borsh.struct([], 'Started'); // No additional data for this variant

// Variant for RoundEnded (has a 'winner' field of type pubkey)
const RoundEnded = borsh.struct(
  [
    borsh.publicKey('winner'), // Winner is a public key
  ],
  'RoundEnded',
);

// Variant for PrizeWithdrew (no fields)
const PrizeWithdrew = borsh.struct([], 'PrizeWithdrew'); // No additional data for this variant

export const GameState = borsh.rustEnum(
  [Started, RoundEnded, PrizeWithdrew],
  'GameState',
);


and the typescript compiler says
TypeError: defaultLayout must be null or a Layout
help me fix this plz
